# Вопрос по javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
for (var b = 0;b < a.tmp.length;b++) {
   var table = '<th>'+a.tmp[b]+'</th>';
}
```

Последнее значение `b = 7`, как сделать чтобы оно выводило не последнее значение `a.tmp[7]`, а по порядку - от `a.tmp[0]` до `a.tmp[7]`, то есть `a.tmp[0] a.tmp[1] a.tmp[2] a.tmp[3]` и т.п

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так примерно

```
var table;
var a=[1,2,3,4];
table = '<th>' + a[0] + '</th>';
for (var b = 1; b < a.length; b++) {
    table += '<th>' + a[b] + '</th>';
}
console.log(table);
```

Все дело в том, что вы в коде при каждой итерации цикла создаете новую table 
`var table = '<th>'+a.tmp[b]+'</th>';`, а вам нужно ее заполнять

Answer (score 1):

[@in1](/users/20503/in1), вы перезаписываете `table` на каждой итерации, поэтому в нем остается только последнее значение. Вам нужно либо выводить значение в цикле, либо записывать его в массив / объект.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло